# Access auth data in web2py static javascript files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web2py

I'm building an app using web2py on the backend (largely just auth and a rest service), and reactjs on the front end. I've decided to place my reactjs files in static/js/... and load it into the html files via the script tag.

Now if I need to access auth related data in my reactjs files in static, e.g. I want to decide whether to check whether I have a user logged in, what's the recommended way to do this?

Should I set global javascript variables in the view files which are visible in the static javascript files, or should I just put all my javascript code into the script elements in the view files (yikes), so that I can use {{}} tags with python code?

Comment: Are you building an SPA? How are you authenticating users? If everything is handled via Ajax, presumably you wouldn't be including any auth data in any web2py views -- all data would be exchanged via the Ajax calls.

Comment: Hi Anthony. Thanks for the reply! I plan to use jwt and web2py auth via the navbar. It's not an SPA, I'm just loading some data in my page. How should I get the jwt token in my script to put in the http header of the Ajax call?

Comment: First, are you aware of web2py's new [JWT functionality](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/0e4ff553061755716599b78082eea331c230a34d/gluon/tools.py#L1129)? Second, even if not using that, what auth data do you need access to in your React code? Presumably, your Javascript code can make an Ajax request for the token.

Comment: ah yes i've started looking at that. it appears that AuthJWT is not coupled with the built in auth/login/register pieces, so if I want to use the login form I'll have to write my own and setup the JWT pieces manually? As to auth data I would like access to - for example I might want to check if a user is already logged in, usually that would just to check whether auth.user is None.

Comment: If using AuthJWT, you would register as usual. For login, you would have to get the username (or email) and password from the user (via your own custom login form), and then make an Ajax request to get the JWT token. On the client side, once you've got the token, you know the user is logged in, so no need to check the value of `auth.user`.

Comment: thanks for all the info so far!  now, a different flavour of the original question: if i want to pass data from the web2py controller to my static javascript files (i.e. not via ajax), what would the recommended method to do this be, given that the static javascript files have no access to the python variables. should i then set global javascript variables in the view files which can be accessed in the static javascript files? or is there a better way?

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be global Javascript variables, but yes, you could write some Javascript code in a view file that interacts with your static Javascript (e.g., calling a function, setting properties on an object, etc.).

Comment: thanks for the help Anthony! i'm looking at other issues at the moment but i'll get back if i need more help on this.